# Rails Dynamic / Cascading Select dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am a relative beginner and have been trying to get this to work.

On my form I want to populate the Rooms select using Ajax once the Location has been selected (on_change).

I have roughly followed this - https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/ - but I cannot quite get it to work.

Form

```
<%= form_for @booking do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :booked_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :booked_date, order: [:month, :day, :year], start_year: 2018 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.select :location_id, options_for_select(@locations.collect { |location| [location.name.titleize, location.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'locations_select' } %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.select :room_id, options_for_select(@rooms.collect { |room| [room.name.titleize, room.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'rooms_select' } %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= form.time_select :start_time %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= form.time_select :end_time %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :meeting_subject %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :subject %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit "Make this booking" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

bookings_controller

```
def update_rooms
    @rooms = Room.where("location_id = ?", params[:location_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#show'

  resources :users
  resources :bookings

  resources :locations do
    resources :rooms
  end


  resources :rooms do
    resources :bookings
  end

  get 'bookings/update_rooms', as: 'update_rooms'

end
```

update_rooms.JS

```
    $("#rooms_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @rooms)) %>")


bookings.js.coffee

$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#locations_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_rooms',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        location_id: $("#locations_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic location select OK!")
```

Partial rooms/_room.html.erb

```
<option value="<%= room.id %>"><%= room.name %></option>
```

When I run the page and change the Location select I get this error:

> Started GET "/bookings/update_rooms?location_id=2&_=1536181850165" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-05 22:10:52 +0100
>
> AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be
>   found for BookingsController:
>
> Started GET "/bookings/update_rooms?location_id=1&_=1536181850166" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-05 22:11:20 +0100
>
> AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be
>   found for BookingsController:

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be
>   found for BookingsController

The problem is that custom route which you have specified is **conflicting** with `show` route of the `bookings`. You need to place the custom route **above** `resources :bookings` to avoid that error and to map that route to `update_rooms` action

```
get 'bookings/update_rooms', as: 'update_rooms'
resources :bookings
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful and such a simple solution.

I now get a new error:

Started GET "/bookings/update_rooms?location_id=3&_=1536239939020" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-06 14:19:04 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#update_rooms as JS
  Parameters: {"location_id"=>"3", "_"=>"1536239939020"}
No template found for BookingsController#update_rooms, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 132ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: @Simonp27 What is your file name? It should be `update_rooms.js.erb`

Comment: Perfect.  It actually needs to be upgrade_rooms.js.erb but you got me in the right direction. THANK YOU.

Comment: Hi, How would I add a default value if there are no rooms to populate?  I would like to say "Sorry no rooms at this location"